# AND NOT LIKE statements together with IN clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to reduce the size of my SQL. Currently I'm using the following to exclude certain deal_id from it. Basically, there is a separate AND NOT line for each deal_id.

Is it possible to have one line below that will include both deal_id (200001 & 300001)?

I will need to have exactly the same wildcards as below. Can the IN clause be used here or do I need something else?

`AND NOT description LIKE '%Error retrieving%Failed%deals deal_id = 200001,%'`

`AND NOT description LIKE '%Error retrieving%Failed%deals deal_id = 300001,%'`

Comment: Is the erroring `deal_id` stored properly as a number in these error logs or whatever this table is? Matching against that would be far easier than depending on arbitrary text in the `description`. Then you could just use `where deal_id not in (200001, 300001)`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't just exclude the deal_id. I need this segment as well: '%Error retrieving%Failed

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp_like()`:

```
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(description, 'Error retrieving.*Failed.*deals deal_id = (200001|200001),')
```

Comment: I added this: AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(description, 'Error retrieving.*Failed.*deals deal_id = (200001|200001),'

Comment: Gordon, mate, I owe you one beer:-) That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!